# ftell returning inaccurate value

Tags: c, ftell

So, I have this piece of code in c that is supposed to read from an ascii file and then return a string that is parsed and compiled into bytecode. When I try to get the size of a file using ftell, it returns 33 rather than 29 (the amount of bytes that the file has including new lines).

the file:

```
push #25
nop
push #44
add
hlt
```

the code:

```
uint8_t* read_ascii_file(uint8_t* path) {
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    uint32_t size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * size);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;
    fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file);
    buffer[size] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

Four more bytes are added for seemingly no reason. My parser complains that "hlt====" is not a valid instruction ("====" are the 4 extra bytes).

Ftell or fseek is messing up in this situation and I don't know if it is a bug or not

I'm on Windows and I'm also using visual studio

Comment: Can you `hexdump` the file? Your end-of-lines might be containing `\r\n`

Comment: You should check your file with a hex editor, to see what bytes are actually there. Also, notice that `buffer[size] = '\0';` is invalid and will produce undefined behavior! Last valid position in `buffer` is `size - 1`.

Comment: It's 4 more bytes than you expect, strongly suggesting to me your line endings are indeed `\r\n` as suggested, accounting for the extra 4 bytes for the first 4 lines. Either way, you still need to allocate enough memory as others have said.

Comment: For starters, I suggest setting `size = fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file);`, so you're sure that `size` contains precisely the number of characters you actually read, not how many you predicted you'd read.

Comment: Whoever taught you to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file taught you wrong.  For a text stream, [the `ftell()` function doesn't return an offset](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2):  "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**"

Comment: And you can't use a binary stream, [because it's undefined behavior to `fseek()` to the end of a binary stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream..."

Comment: @SteveSummit [`stat()` is more portable than its naysayers claim...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-160)

Comment: To read all of a file into a buffer correctly, allocate a buffer of any size (as with `malloc`), and read data into it, up to the size of the buffer (allowing space for a terminating null character if you wish). If the function you are using to read has not indicated the end-of-file was reached, then increase the size of the buffer (with `realloc`) and read more, putting the new data just after the previous data. Repeat until end-of-file is reached or memory allocation fails…

Comment: … It is okay to set the initial buffer size based on some attempt to find out how big the file is, but it is not okay to assume you will actually read that many bytes from the file, for multiple reasons (`ftell` does not provide the desired information or the file changes between getting its size and reading it). You must be prepared to handle whatever number of bytes come from reading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space.

You allocate `sizeof(uint8_t) * size` bytes for the file contents, however this isn't enough to hold the null byte that you later add to terminate the string.  So you write past the bounds of allocated memory, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Add 1 to leave space for the null terminator.

```
uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * size + 1);
```

Also, these lines are problematic:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file);
buffer[size] = '\0';
```

Because of the translation of newlines on windows, you'll end up reading in less bytes then the file actually contains.  This means the teminating null byte is in the wrong place.

Save the return value of `fread` which will tell you how many bytes you *actually* read, then use that value to write the null byte.

```
size_t rval = fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file);
if (rval > 0) {
    buffer[rval] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Size is still 33. Like @Eugene Sh. mentioned it could be that the new lines contain \r\n. I'm on Windows, how do I make it so it reads new lines properly?

Comment: @Agent_Honky_007 It is reading newlines properly -- it's translating `\r\n` in the file to `\n` as seen by your program.  That's how text files are defined to behave in C.  If you update `size` based on `fread`'s return value, things should work better for you.  (Can't say that'll solve all your problems, however.)